# Does not exist or no pull access(Docker compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to dockerize my spring-boot/spring-cloud application.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
eureka:
  build: ./eureka-discovery-service
  ports:
    - "8761:8761"

mongodb:
  image: mongo:3.0.4
  ports:
    - "32768:32768"

postgresql:
  image: postgresql:9.6-2
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

gateway-service:
  build: ./gateway-service
  ports:
    - "9090:9090"
  links:
    - eureka

airplane-service:
  build: ./airplane-service
  ports:
    - "2222:2222"
  links:
    - eureka
    - postgresql

car-service:
  build: ./car-service
  ports:
    - "2220:2220"
  links:
    - eureka
    - mongodb

machine-service:
  build: ./machine-service
  ports:
    - "2224:2224"
  links:
    - eureka
```

I'm getting the below error message when doing a *docker-compose up*:

```
Pulling postgresql (postgresql:9.6-2)...
ERROR: repository postgresql not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

How solve this problem and why I have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The image name should be `postgres:9.6.4`